# Do you say "thank you" to commenters who solve your problem?

Tags: discussion, questions, comment

I have this question of etiquette. I was wondering if at the end of a discussion in the comment section a question, once my doubt has been clarified, should I add a final comment thanking the person who took the time, or if that is not in tune with the site's etiquette.

Comment: It is useful to clarify that the comment resolved your doubts!

Comment: Ok, then thank you too!

Comment: I'd say that CV is more indulgent to comments than is common elsewhere on SE, especially Stack Overflow. A good reason for that: what to do or even what to think can be an open or controversial question on CV. Another good reason is that many questions aren't clear-cut and comments often ask for more details.  Particularly after several comments, it's good to see some thanks. An extra reason for that is that an answer saying Thanks is highly likely to be removed.

Comment: The site wide policy is in the [help](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help), specifically for thanking people, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers), but in practice there's a little more leeway on what comments can contain is typcally given here, but a bare thank you comment is likely to be removed as Nick suggests.

Comment: There are many threads in which the comments are more interesting and/or better informed than the answers, but it would be indelicate to give precise examples. Naturally, if one has scope to give a better answer than the existing answers, it would be good to write it down, but life is short and complicated. For example, many questions on outliers just presume that outliers should just be removed, period, but explaining again and again that  this is far from the only view in town is more than I want to do.

Comment: Ideally any information in the comments that's particularly useful and relevant to the general question or answer would make its way into a post, and the corresponding comments would be deleted, in which case whether or not you thank them shouldn't matter all that much. Comments are not really built for the long-term storage and presentation of useful information. Although in practice this ideal doesn't always make sense or work so well.

Answer (score 16):

We commonly edit out "thanks" from the body of a question (see revision history on this Q).  In the question, we want to get as quickly as possible to—and through—the relevant information.

On the other hand, at the end of a comment thread, or after an answer, "thanks" is more tolerated.